# connect to all phones near me via socket(android)

Tags: java, android

I want to connect phone to all devices near me via socket, but for this I need all ip adresses.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("IP","PORT");
```

How I can get all phone IP addresses to which the socket reaches?

Answer (score 0):

To connect other devices you need to run listener on other devices too. after this get your phone's IP address, and try to connect every lan IP from 1 to 255. for example your IP is 192.168.1.25 . take 192.168.1. and add number from 1 to 255 and try to connect it to each. Don't forget to set timeout for waiting, otherwise it will take too much time to wait non existed IP addresses.
This is how to get your IP address:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

This is how to set timeout:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(100)
```